# Extract substring from a file

Tags: python

I have a huge log file from which I have to extract a particular pattern or byte array.
Each line looks something like this:

```
<<< 10:39:01.296  [0x01|0x02|0x04|0x05] [0x00|0xDE|0xAD]   (Value: Check)
```

From this line I have to extract the Bytes 0xDE and 0xAD.

The log pattern is usually of the form ( only XX and YY are variants) :

```
<<< 10:39:01.296  [0x01|0x02|0x04|0x05] [0x00|0xXX|0xYY]   (Value: Check)
```

To try out, I have this pattern as a string and the following code to check. However I feel there must be a better way than this. Can you please advise?

```
input= """<<< 10:39:01.296  [0x01|0x02|0x04|0x05] [0x00|0xDE|0xAD]   (Value: Check) """

#extract 0xDE and 0xAD and join them to read DEAD


c = input.find("]")
d = input.find('[', c)
e = input.find("]", d)
mystr =  input[d+6:e]
x,y = mystr.split('|0x', 1)

print x
print y
numStr =  ''.join(mystr.split('|0x', 1))


print numStr
#val = int(numStr,16)
#print val:
```

Comment: Question is little unclear  .will it be always 0xDE and 0xAD . .that you want to extract , or you need to get the last two bytes ??

Answer (score 0):

If the format always has three bytes in the second block, the first block never has three bytes, and you only care about the second two bytes of the block, then here are a couple approaches.

One approach is to simplify your search for the block in question by starting the search from the right and using an exception raising search method (so you don't need to check return values explicitly to see if the `find` succeeded, just `try`/`except` and skip the line if it doesn't have the expected data):

```
mystr = input[input.rindex('[')+1:input.rindex(']')]
byteparts = mystr.split('|')
byte1, byte2 = byteparts[1:]  # Unlike the above, this keeps the 0x, but that's trivially stripped if you care
# By using [1:] as the slice and unpacking the result, if you got a set
# of matches that isn't three bytes long, you'll get an exception on unpack
```

The use of `rindex` means you can ignore the first block (you never get to it), and if the search fails, it raises an error immediately instead of returning -1 and misbehaving silently.

Another solution is to use a regular expression (and I say this reluctantly; too many people reach for regular expressions as a first resort, which is usually a bad idea, but for sufficiently weird cases, is sometimes better than building your logic from method calls). This would solve the stated problem, and could handle much more complex variants by tweaking the regex:

```
import re

input = ...

match = re.search(r'\[0x..\|0x([0-9a-f]{2})\|0x([0-9a-f]{2})\]', input, re.I)

if match is not None:
    byte1, byte2 = match.groups()
```

Comment: Note: regular expressions are useful here if the problem is even a little more complicated that what you've given. If it's solvable with the `rindex` approach, I'd stick with that.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a regular expression, and your log pattern always look like your sample, you could do an ugly one-liner

```
print ''.join(item.replace('0x', '') for item in input.split('[')[2].split(']')[0].split('|')[1:])
>>> 'DEAD'
```

Answer (score 0):

With the question as stated, the following will output what you want but somehow I get the feeling that your question is not what it seems and there is a big something missing.

```
>>> res = ''.join(input[46:55].split('|0x',1)).split('0x',1)[1]
>>> if res == 'DEAD': print res
... 
DEAD
```

or how about:

```
>>> input= "<<< 10:39:01.296  [0x01|0x02|0x04|0x05] [0x00|0xDE|0xAD]   (Value: Check) "
>>> if '|0xDE|0xAD]' in input:
...     print "DEAD occurred at ", input[4:16]
... 
DEAD occurred at  10:39:01.296
```

or:

```
>>> if input.rfind('|0xDE|0xAD]') > 40:
...     print "DEAD occurred at ", input[4:16]
... 
DEAD occurred at  10:39:01.296
```

Comment: Even if you could use magic numbers (because the line has fixed layout), I'd feel really uncomfortable doing so for maintainability reasons; the logic of the code says almost nothing about what it is looking for, so if the log format changes, you'd need to reference old logs just to interpret the code enough to update it. That's assuming you even notice the problem; this will misbehave and produce incorrect output in many cases, and never raise an exception of any kind (even when operating on the empty string).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I agree but then that is why I also added a rather large caveat. If the question changes, or there is a comment that makes it clearer what is being attempted, I will happily delete this answer.

Comment: No, my point is that, even if the problem is *exactly* what you think it is, magic numbers and no error checking are dangerous, because problems change, and even if they don't people need to read the code later and have some idea what it's supposed to do.

I agree it probably solves the problem, it's just a bad idea even if it does.

Comment: @ShadowRanger and still I agree but look at the original code, is it really any worse than what was already there. Until the OP comes back with some sort of reply we just don't know what they want, super-dooper catch all, maintainable code or a fast dirty fix

Answer (score 0):

The last two numbers could be extracted as follows:

```
import re

text = "<<< 10:39:01.296  [0x01|0x02|0x04|0x05] [0x00|0xDE|0xAD]   (Value: Check)"
parts = re.split(r'[|\]]', text)

print int(parts[-3], 16)
print int(parts[-2], 16)
```

Giving:

```
222
173
```

Note: it is best not to use an variable called [`input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=input#input) as this is built-in Python function.